# Why does using sum() here require a higher-ranked trait bound?

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime, higher-rank-types

Im writing a generic matrix library in Rust, and wanted to make a dot product function

this:

```rust
pub fn dot<'a, R: Scalar>(&'a self, rhs: &'a Matrix<R, M, 1>) -> T
where
    T: Sum<&'a T>,
    &'a Self: Mul<&'a Vector<R, M>, Output = Self>,
{
    (self * rhs).elements().sum::<T>()
}
```

caused a confusing error I didn't understand:

```
304 |     pub fn dot<'a, R: Scalar>(&'a self, rhs: &'a Matrix<R, M, 1>) -> T
    |                -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
309 |         (self * rhs).elements().sum::<T>()
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^-----------
    |         |
    |         creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
    |         argument requires that borrow lasts for `'a`
310 |     }
    |     - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
```

After searching for similar issues blindly trying different things, I came to the solution of

```rust
pub fn dot<'a, R: Scalar>(&'a self, rhs: &'a Matrix<R, M, 1>) -> T
where
    T: for<'b> Sum<&'b T>,
    &'a Self: Mul<&'a Vector<R, M>, Output = Self>,
{
    (self * rhs).elements().sum::<T>()
}
```

this works, *but I don't understand why its necessary*. Why is the temporary not lasting the length of the entire function block? and what is the lifetime that `'b` is referring to?

##### Context:

`Matrix` is

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct Matrix<T, const M: usize, const N: usize>
where
    T: Scalar,
{
    data: [[T; N]; M], // Column-Major order
}
```

and `Vector` is

```rust
pub type Vector<T, const N: usize> = Matrix<T, N, 1>;
```

`elements()` returns a flattened iterator over `data`. `mul` returns the same type as `Self`. I get the same error if I change the `dot()` body to:

`self.clone().data[0].iter().sum::<T>()`

so it isn't an issue with other methods on `Matrix`

the same thing also happens if I assign `self * rhs` to a variable

Comment: Please make your example [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How is `Mul` implemented? What does the `elements` method return?

Comment: done, added some context and an example that doesnt use any external methods at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using *too many* lifetime annotations as is. If you actually think about the lifetimes you've given the compiler, it's right. You are dropping the temporary while it's still in use. With the bound `T: Sum<&'a T>` you've told it that a `T` can be made from `&'a T`s. And `'a` is *the same* lifetime for which `self` is borrowed. **But**: `&Self * &Vector<R, M>` returns a new, *owned* `Self`, call it `P`, that lives only for the remainder of the function, call that lifetime `'p`.

Now, `elements` probably has a signature along the lines of `fn elements<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a T>` (maybe some of those lifetimes are actually elided, but they're still there). So when you call `P.elements`, you're calling, essentially, `elements(&'p P) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'p T>`.

Then, when you call `sum::<T>` on that, the compiler only knows how to `sum` a new `T` from `&'a T`s, so it infers that `'p` must be equal to `'a`. But they're clearly not. `'p` only lasts to the end of the function while `'a` keeps on living. That's why you're getting the error: You've tied the `T` you're returning to the lifetime of `self` for no reason.

A rule of thumb I've not thought too hard about but might still be useful is: if you borrow `self` immutably and the return type doesn't capture a lifetime (i.e. isn't a reference, a trait object, an `impl Trait`, or a caller supplied generic), you probably don't need to specify the arguments' lifetimes.

That is to say: you don't care about the lifetimes of `self` or `rhs` because you're returning an owned type that doesn't reference either of them.

Of course, you'll still need lifetimes in your `where` clause and that's where `for<'x> _: ...` comes in. That's called a [HRTB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) and basically says, "for any lifetime I plug into `'x` what comes after the `:` will be valid." *That's* what you care about. That it works as long as you only have references, not as long as you have references that live for any particular `'x`.

So you can simply re-write `dot`'s signature like this

```
pub fn dot<R: Scalar>(&self, rhs: &Matrix<R, M, 1>) -> T
where
    for<'x> T: Sum<&'x T>,
    for<'y> &'y Self: Mul<&'y Vector<R, M>, Output = Self>,
{ // ...
```